# Killing all instances of Chrome on the command-line?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, bash

In some cases killing a single tab/process doesn't do it and I need to close Chrome entirely. Since Chrome has multiple processes, how can I close all of them at once?

I know that...

`pgrep chrome` returns all the pids. What is a trick that would allow me to close all of them by feeding them to another command or merging them to a CSV file or something?

Comment: Since there are at least three answers here that needlessly do `kill -9`, here are three reference discussing the reasons that should be your last choice: [When should I use kill -9](http://aplawrence.com/SCOFAQ/FAQ_scotec6killminus9.html), [kill -9](http://speculation.org/garrick/kill-9.html) and [Useless use of kill -9](http://sial.org/howto/shell/kill-9/).

Comment: Similar question in the U/Linux site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34101/6272

Comment: The cleanest answer really is the one from questions on other sites, as noted below, since it figures out which one process to kill by the oldest timestamp: `pkill --oldest chrome`

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Try using **[pkill(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)**.

`pkill chrome`

Comment: just be aware that pkill might not be on all systems, but if you have pgrep, more than likely pkill exists as well.

Comment: for me this was case sensitive, I needed to write `pkill Chrome`

Comment: Didn't work fork for me. Using `pkill chrome` It didn't close the main chrome process. It closed all the internal processes causing crashes on all extensions. Also, it caused some of the windows to not open on the next launch, causing loss of state :(

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka - You might try explicitly killing the oldest Chrome process with something like `pkill --oldest chrome`

Answer (score 21):

```
ps aux | grep chrome | awk ' { print $2 } ' | xargs kill -9
```

or

```
pgrep chrome | xargs kill -9
```

or

```
ps aux | awk '/chrome/ { print $2 } ' | xargs kill -9
```

The latter is more "elegant" as it will not pick up the actual pid for "grep chrome" inside of its ps listing

:-)

Comment: Is there any reason to use `ps ... | ` instead of `pgrep`, even supposing you don't want to use `pkill`?

Comment: It's also always polite to start with SIGTERM before escalating to SIGKILL.

Comment: not really, only reason i threw the ps option out there is due to alot of my systems are bare bones meaning we dont have things like pkill pgrep

Comment: I agree, but one just asked to kill :-O

s/-9/-1/g

Answer (score 6):

Some systems may also have useful programs such as `killall` and `pidof` (which is actually provided by the System V `killall5`):

```
killall chrome
kill -9 `pidof chrome`
```

Both of these should accomplish what you are asking.

Comment: You shouldn't use `-9` except as a last resort. Do `kill PID` first.

Comment: `killall` also supports case insensitivity, for example: `killall --ignore-case ChRomE` would kill all Chrome processes. The option `--ignore-case` can also be shortened to `-I`. Unfortunately, `pkill` does not support case-insensitivity - at least on the Linux systems I have tried (but it does support `-i` for case-insensitivity on MacOS).

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/bin/pkill --oldest --signal TERM -f chrome` worked perfectly.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174451/6272

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should really just use `pkill` as jschmier suggests, but if you insist on pgrep, just use command substitution:

```
kill $(pgrep chrome)
```

Comment: would'nt 

`kill `pgrep chrome`` also work ;)

Comment: @kSiR: [a month late] yes, but `$(...)` is a great habit to get into so you can nest when you need to, and flip between matching delimiters in your editor.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest command is this one:

```
sudo killall chrome
```

This will, with administrative permissions, kill all processes that contain `chrome` in their name.

See `man killall` for more information...

Comment: Could you add a bit of explanation about how your answer works?

Answer (score 1):

Under Ubuntu, this is what worked for me:

pkill **chromium**

Comment: Of course also works just fine on a Mac via the VS Code terminal if for example doing some testing in Chromium (which can lead to allot of open instances)

Comment: Oh, and on Mac it's usually "pkill Chromium" with a capital 'C'

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

```
ps -C chrome |cut -f 1 -d' ' | xargs kill
```

Comment: You shouldn't use -9 except as a last resort. Do `kill PID` first.

Comment: good point. I updated my answer.

Comment: No need for another pipe through `cut`; `ps` can do it itself: `ps -o pid= -C chrome | xargs kill`.

Comment: And it's a good habit to put `-r` in `xargs`: `ps -o pid= -C chrome | xargs -r kill`.

Comment: @musiphil: what is -r?

Comment: `-r` is identical to `--no-run-if-empty`; i.e. "If the standard input is completely empty, do not run the command."
You can look it up from `man xargs` or `info xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way:

```
kill -9 $(pgrep -d' ' -f chrome)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect there are other processes called chrome, yolou can use pgrep to search for processes with a given name.

Answer (score 0):

To close all chrome instances on macOS:

```
pkill -9 "Google Chrome"
```